# numpy - slicing a 3d array, how to apply two slices of different length in a certain axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have been stuck with a question about slicing numpy array for a while.

Below is an array I have right now:

```
a = np.array([[[ 1,  2],
               [ 3,  4],
               [ 5,  6]],
              [[ 7,  8],
               [ 9, 10],
               [11, 12]]]
```

How can I use slicing to get an array like the following?

```
np.array([[[ 1,  2]],
          [[ 9, 10],
           [11, 12]]]
```

I have tried `a[[0,1],[0,[1,2]]` however it didn't work and gave an error:
`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I dont understand any pattern on what rows you want returned so I'm going to err on the side of this not being possible in a general case

Comment: Your result block will be a 1d 2 element array, containing a (1,2) and (2,2) array (or lists).  You just have to take the two slices separately.

Comment: @hpaulj That's kind of what I thought. Thank you though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact thing you give as your desired output is not possible, since arrays have to be "hyper-rectangles", so `X[0].shape` has to be the same as `X[1].shape`.

What you can do is:

```
a[[0,1,1],[0,1,2]]
# array([[ 1,  2],
#        [ 9, 10],
#        [11, 12]])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Accepted this since this works for me and was the earliest one.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, for example:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[[ 1,  2], [ 3,  4], [ 5,  6]], [[ 7,  8], [ 9, 10], [11, 12]]])



print(np.array([[a[0, 0 ,: ],  a[1, 1 ,:], a[1, 2 ,: ]]]))
```

Result:

```
[[[ 1  2]
 [ 9 10]
 [11 12]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply two operations separably and merge them afterwards:

```
np.array((a[0,0:1].tolist(), a[1,1:].tolist()))
# array([[[1, 2]], [[9, 10], [11, 12]]], dtype=object)
```